# Load UTF-8 text or html file and add it to dom with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, utf-8, readfile

I want to read content of a txt or HTML file (some HTML element saved in before) and add them to current page. (like importing template in sliders). I found this code That's work correctly:

```js
    var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var output;
    document.getElementById('myFile').addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var myFile = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                document.getElementById("aDivToShowResult").innerHTML = e.target.result;
            });

            reader.readAsText(myFile);
        }        
    });
```

```html
  <input type="file" id="myFile">
<div id="aDivToShowResult">

</div>
```

But my content contain UTF-8 characters!!
(my page totally has UTF-8 charset but Note that the page does not reload when adding code!!
also the txt file saved in UTF-8)
how can I read file and its content(and add to DOM) by UTF-8 charset by JS??
If this is not possible, is there a library or other code to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You did great, you just have one tiny mistake: if you do `innerHTML` it will expect to receive some HTML. But you want to add text, right? Then you have to use the method: `element.innerText = 'your text'`

It's different because the later generates a text node, while the first will try to parse some HTML and add it to the DOM as Element Nodes.

Here's some reference:

- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
var output;
document.getElementById('myFile').addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var myFile = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
            document.getElementById("aDivToShowResult").innerText = e.target.result;
        });

        reader.readAsText(myFile);
    }        
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<div id="aDivToShowResult"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly my goal is to add the contents of the .txt file as  DOM Element Nodes. For example in the .txt file this is saved: <img src = "..." style = "..."> and I want to add it as img Node to DOM